Cisco 7962 stuck at registering
I have isabell astrisk on a VPS and I have Cisco 7962G in my office.
I converted 7962 to SIP firmware and configed as this file :
https://ctxt.io/2/AAB4MRCdFQ
I can connect my extension with softphone but on cisco it stuck on registering

This is off-topic here as it has nothing to do with programming. This seems like a very specific support question, which is also off-topic here - see Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow? This might fit on [networkengineering.se], but you need to read the guidelines first. Also, if you post there, remember that all relevant details need to be in your question, not as a link to some external site.
